# How to save a Xml web page content as a XML document in local drive using C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, xml

How to save a below Xml web page content as a XML document in local drive using C# .Net.
URL is as below : 
http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote

I want to load few field values into oracle DB table in a daily basis. Please help me to code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as saving the XML as a local file, I have put together the following code.

```
System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();

string webData = wc.DownloadString("http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote");

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\YOUR_FILE_PATH\FILE_NAME.xml", webData);
```

Just replace YOUR_FILE_PATH and FILE_NAME with where you want to save the data and your desired file name and it should be good.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I am trying this solution, "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable." occurs. But i tried to access the sam URL in deployed server, it is accessible.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why the server would be unavailable. I just ran it on my local machine and it works fine over here. Where are you running the code from?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at XMLDocument class

you can use method Load to load your xml and Save to save it to a file

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Useful inofrmation friend. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

First you need to generate the C# classes for your XML.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh371548(v=vs.110).aspx
The summary is you copy the xml text and then in a code file but outside of a class, click menu Edit -> Paste Special -> Paste XML as Classes

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer(v=vs.110).aspx
Then you can then load the xml file using XmlSerialzer

From there you can use push it to your oracle DB through Entity Framework Connection.

code to deserialize into a list object:

```
string url = "http://finance.yahoo.com/webservice/v1/symbols/allcurrencies/quote";
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(list));
HttpWebRequest aRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse aResponse = (HttpWebResponse)aRequest.GetResponse();

list mylist = (list)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(aResponse.GetResponseStream());
```

Then you can use mylist as any object.

Comment: When i tried your code, i received the casting error. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Net.FileWebRequest' to type 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest'."

Comment: Assuming that you are getting the error on the WebRequest.Create(url) call. Create returns a WebRequest as per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.create(v=vs.110).aspx.  Not sure how you are Creating a FileWebRequest.